# Assign Roles to Directory Pages in Membership and Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am creating a web application and i am using membership and roles. In my application i have 4 Roles.

1. Admin
2. Receptionist
3. Scheduler
4. Accountant

i have one page of registerpatient.aspx common in both receptionist and Scheduler. Means both can create a patient. then in which folder i should put this page so that both can access. i dont want any other user to access this page. I am using Roles management by membership and roles. so we can assign roles to Directory so how to assign to particular pages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding location configuration. Location is a web.config section that apply for only one directory or file and contains its own system.web section. See a post about that here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx